# ssh pipeline command error

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

I am running on a machine

```
ssh root@lPServerHgl  cat /root/devops/giveAllArtifacts.txt | xargs -I {} sh -c "grep {} /ci/test.log;"
```

I am getting grep: /ci/test.log: No such file or directory

but the same command(`cat /root/devops/giveAllArtifacts.txt | xargs -I {} sh -c "grep {} /ci/test.log;"`) on the server:lPServerHgl is working as it should without any error.

P.S ssh connection doesn't have any problems.All other commands are working over ssh.There seems to be some problem with piped commands.

Answer (score 4):

The pipe is running on your local computer, not on the remote server.

```
ssh user@host remote-cmd [...args] | local-cmd [...args]
--------- runs in server --------- | --- runs locally ----
```

The pipe is interpreted by *your* shell, not the remote one. To execute a pipeline on the other side of the `ssh` connection, you have invoke a shell there. For example:

```
ssh user@host bash -c "'cat file.txt | grep foo'"
```

Note the inner quotes. This will send the pipeline to a `bash` process on the other machine.

Typing these commands can be troublesome and bug-prone. You may want to place a ready-to-run script on the remote machine, to call it with a single command.

Comment: to test if what you said is correct i ran this
ssh user@host  ls -l /ci | grep drwx
and it gave  remotehost result instead of local machine.
And invoking bash twice is not working because i am doing that already in xrags sh -c

Comment: `ssh user@host bash -c "cat file.txt | grep foo"` This doesn't quite work. ssh is going to end up invoking `bash -c cat file.txt | grep foo` on the remote, which doesn't do what's intended.

Comment: any other way to to specify to ssh that its a single command to be executed on remote.I tried this 


ssh root@lPServerHgl  `cat /root/devops/giveAllArtifacts.txt | xargs -I {} sh -c "grep {} /ci/test.log;"`

but still doesn't work

Comment: When you ran `| grep`, the `grep` command ran locally. The output of the remote command was given to the local `grep`. The `sh` command in your example is also running locally, so there's no two remote bash instances. I added inner quotes to the example above to fix it (it was, as you pointed out, broken). Use the updated answer

Comment: unfortunately, that is also not working.
ssh user@remote bash -c "cat file"
is leaving a blank screen.
Also, ssh user@host bash -c "'cat file.txt | grep foo'"
leaving a black screen with no output.

Comment: Try this: `ssh user@host bash -c "'seq 10 | grep 1'"`. Guaranteed to work, and runs both programs on the remote machine. The principle is the same for your example. Just in case: `user` is your user, `host` is your host, and `file.txt` was made up: replace those with your actual values, the commands I wrote won't work verbatim

Comment: Your command, as posted in the question, has inner quotes. You'll have to use something like `$(xargs ...)` to appropriately quote them. As I said, you're better off placing a script on the server -- this is all just so you understand the problem